# Debian partial Mirror - “debpartial-mirror” specific mirroring

Tags: debian, apt, repository, mirror

I am using Debian 7.3 with `debpartial-mirror` in order to create and maintain an offline mirror. 
Since I need only the basic packages (packages needed for installation via PXEboot and maybe the most common packages that are installed afterwards), I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Right now, the mirror is trying to clone the whole archive, but I don't need all packages, nor do I have a good connection to the internet to maintain the archive properly if it is that big.

my debpartial-mirrir.conf is :

```
;;
;; debpartial-mirror configuration file.
;;

[GLOBAL]
;; Show debug information?
;;debug = DEBUG

;; Mirror destination directory
mirror_dir = /install/debian/debpartial-mirror/

;; Which architectures should I download?
architectures = amd64

;; What should I look for, by default?
components = main contrib non-free
distributions = stable

;; What should I get?
get_suggests = true
get_recommends = true
get_provides = true
get_sources = false
get_packages = true

[wheezy]
server = http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian
components = main contrib non-free
distributions = stable
;;filter = subsection:base priority:important
get_sources =false

[wheezy-updates]
server = http://ftp.debian.org/debian
components = main contrib non-free
distributions = wheezy-updates
filter = subsection:base priority:important
resolve_deps_using = wheezy


[wheezy-security]
server = http://security.debian.org/
components = main contrib non-free
distributions = wheezy/updates
filter = subsection:base priority:important
resolve_deps_using = wheezy

[wheezy_debian-installer]
server = http://ftp.debian.org/debian
components = main/debian-installer
distributions = wheezy
```

Comment: `;; What should I look for, by default?
components = main contrib non-free
distributions = stable` your problem is here I guess your asking for everything, I think `contrib` and `non-free` are useless for basics installation

Comment: thanks.  will have a look into it on monday. Right now i have another test running. since debpartial wont tell you in forhand how big the mirror is going to be and my slow connection, i will have to wait for current test to finish.

I will keep you up to date